# Was bedeutet *etwas auf sich halten* in gegebenem Kontext

Tags: translation

Was bedeutet :

> Wer etwas auf sich hielt, legte seinen Dialekt ab,
>   lernte Hochsprache und vermied, den Dialekt auch nur anklingen zu lassen?

Was bedeutet hier genau *etwas auf sich hielt*?

Answer (score 6):

Die Antwort sollten Sie eigentlich in einem Wörterbuch Ihrer Wahl finden. Zum Beispiel in *Duden*, Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, 4. Auflage 2012 (Definition fett hervorgehoben):

> auf sich halten (**auf sein Ansehen, seinen Ruf, sein Image bedacht sein**: wer [ein bisschen] auf sich hält, kann sich in so einer Kaschemme nicht sehen lassen; Wer sich leisten kann, etwas auf sich zu halten, zeigt es und zieht aus der Stadt heraus in die Vororte [Roehler, Würde 83]).

Oder auch im [*DWDS*, Stichwort "halten", Bedeutung 19](https://www.dwds.de/wb/halten). Gemeint ist also, dass diejenigen, die Ansehen / eine gute gesellschaftliche Stellung erlangen wollten, nicht im Dialekt, sondern in der Hochsprache kommunizierten.

"Hoch Sprache" ist im Übrigen ein Wort: *Hochsprache*. Typischerweise wird es außerdem mit Artikel gebraucht: *... legte seinen Dialekt ab, lernte die Hochsprache ...*